# Is it safe to use a 10-Port USB Hub in a laptop?

Tags: laptop, usb, hub

I got lots of USB stuffs connected to my laptop, like:

- Keyboard
- Mouse
- Laptop Cooler
- Phones

I used 4-port USB hub before, but I don't know if 10-port is safe.

Example of a 10-port USB Hub:
http://www.cdrking.com/index.php?mod=products&type=view&sid=16077&main=167

Comment: Sure it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's safe, but i would recommend an externally powered one.

It depends ALOT on the laptop, if it will be able to power the 10-port hub. For example, my Samsung laptop outputs nearly 1A of current from one port, where the limitations to usb standard is 550mA if i remember correctly. My worklaptop, a dell, has trouble powering a 4-port hub.

Comment: I agree. With 10 ports, I rather have it externally powered than worry about current requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is absolutely safe. The only potential problem that arises is exceeding the USB hub power limitations, but luckily a little pop-up will appear that lets you know when this has happened. Your computer won't allow any physical damage if your USB hub is trying to draw too much current so I'd say go for it.